# OAuth consumer stopped working, where do I start debugging?

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, sinatra

I have a small Sinatra app that uses Twitter OAuth for authentication. Some time between October 8th and today, it stopped working.

The symptom: I get redirected to Twitter, I sign in, I get redirected back to my app, but **my app does not recognize me as logged in.**

I can rule out my own code (haven't touched that in a month) and the platform (Heroku is managed, and all the requests look fine).

The relevant part of the code is this (based on [this code](https://github.com/langalex/imonaplane/blob/749cf00ad7b8e77d3b8f3d1c8569ea508bc498ae/app.rb#L103) by Alex Lang):

```rb
get '/session_auth' do
  if params[:oauth_verifier]
    access_token = twitter_client.authorize(
      session[:request_token], session[:request_token_secret], oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier])
    if twitter_client.authorized?
      user = db.load(User.to_id(twitter_client.info['screen_name'])) || User.new(login: twitter_client.info['screen_name'], twitter_access_token: access_token.token,
        twitter_secret_token: access_token.secret)
      db.save! user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
  redirect '/'
end
```

How or where do you start debugging a thing like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **I went up the tool-chain from my app to Twitter.**

Twitter sends back an OAuth verifier parameter to my callback action which is used for the `authorize` call. If the twitter client is authorized after that, the app sets the `user_id` in the session.

The `authorize` and `authorized?` calls are from the [twitter_oauth gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter_oauth). An updated version was released on October 12, fixing the API call for the `authorized?` method (see the [commit on Github](https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth/commit/1928917622443eacbafe461b05faed3ec0a24861)). Jackpot!

So all I had to do was:

```
bundle update twitter_oauth
```

and everything worked again. The only thing I have yet to find out is why twitter_oauth worked before. I suspect Twitter deprecated part of their API URLs, but I'd like to know for sure.